# Check that there are at least two arguments given in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a script that mimics `cp` where there is a source and destination input. How can I count the number of arguments given on the command line?

For example:

```
./myscript src dest
```

How can I check that at least 2 things were given?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use the `$#` special variable. Its value is the number of arguments. So if you have a script that contains only:

```
echo $#
```

and execute it like this:

```
thatscript foo bar baz quux
```

It'll print 4.

In your case you may want to do something like:

```
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    # TODO: print usage
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: If you put it in your `~/.bashrc` use `return` rather than `exit 1`

Answer (score 30):

Going by the requirement from the question that the arguments should contain "at least 2 things", I think it might be more accurate to check:

```
if (( $# < 2 )); then
    # TODO: print usage
    exit 1
fi
```

Using [arithmetic expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) `((` `))` will prevent this from hitting `exit 1` for any value not equal to 2.

If you use `if [ $# -ne 2 ];` it will trigger the conditional for any number of arguments other than 2.

Edit:  It looks like the accepted answer has been updated to include an equivalent (and more portable?) example of this.