# Custom command in linux to move files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to create a command that allows me move a file to another directory. For example when I enter "move file1"  in the command line, it should move the file "file1" to another directory. I know it can simply done as mv file1 /path/to/destination, But I want to create a new command. I'm kind of new Linux user, please help me.

This is what I tried:
Created an alias for move='/home/bin/move.sh'
So, now when I type move in the command line, it goes and execute move.sh script

Started writing a shell script move.sh as :

```
#!/bin/bash

mv "$2" "/path/to/destination"
```

I'm not knowing how to proceed. The whole process might be wrong too. Please help me solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $0 is the name of the exec (move.sh), $1 is the first argument. Change $2 inti $1.

Answer (score 2):

Create a function:

```
move () { mv -t /path/to/destination "$@" ;}
```

put it in `~/.bashrc` to make it permanent.

Now run it as :

```
move /source /files
```

Comment: This worked great too. Thanks heemayl. Little more extension to my question
If I wish to have the command as move -i, instead of just move. How would I do that  ?
I can't assign a function 'move -i'. So, how can I possibly proceed ?

Comment: @Anil Use `-i` inside the command i.e. `move () { mv -it /path/to/destination "$@" ;}`

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_read_command_line_arguments_in_a_bash_script) you can read on how to select arguments.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989486/check-that-there-are-at-least-two-arguments-given-in-a-bash-script) you can read more on how to check for number of arguments.

move.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if (( $# < 2 )); then
    # TODO: print usage
    exit 1
fi
mv "$1" "$2"
```

Then you will need to make it executable.

```
chmod u+x move.sh
```

You can remove the `.sh` part. It wont change anything.

```
mv move.sh move
```

And then you should be able to call the file

```
move asd /home/
```

Just make sure that the alias calls the correct file.

If you want to make life easier delete the alias and place the file in the /bin/ directory

```
cp move /bin/
```

Good luck.

Comment: Do you mind taking a minute to explain the script, please.

Comment: And, If I wish to have the command as move -i, instead of just move. How would I do that  ?
Obviously we can't create a script named move -i (since spaces aren't allowed in the file name), I can't think of a solution for this.